# A problem occurred in the build.gradle file

Tags: flutter, build.gradle

[image]FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\it\StudioProjects\untitled\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> com/google/common/util/concurrent/internal/InternalFutureFailureAccess

Comment: This problem comes after the update.

Comment: Is there a solution? I also got an error after the update.